# Matching years at end of string not enclosed in brackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match strings that have a year at the end of them, but only when they're not enclosed in brackets. Negative lookaheads and lookbehinds don't seem to help.

Here's some example text. I only want the first two lines matched, and not the third.

```
Example one 2015
Example two 2017
Example three (2009)
```

If I use something like `(?<!\(\d{4}\)$)` or `(?!\(\d{4}\)$)` then I get 54 matches instead of the expected 2 (one for each of the first two lines).

[image: screenshot of current regex results]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to define the problem a little bit more here.  Would simply `\d{4}$` be a valid solution?  This will only match when the string ends in 4 digits, which it doesn't if those digits are enclosed in parentheses.  Or do you want the match to capture the whole line, something like `^(?=.*\d{4}$).+$`?  Or something else?

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong The intent is to isolate these lines from a long list, then extract the year from those strings and enclose them in brackets so the strings are all formatted similarly. Two capture groups, I suppose?

Comment: Okay, then you can just separate the `.+` in my previous pattern into two different capturing groups.  Something like this (removed the redundant lookahead): `^(.+)(\d{4})$` and then you can just replace with `$1($2)` (I'm using $ notation here, you can modify it for whatever parser you are using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`^(.*[^\(]\d{4}[^\)]?)$`

- `^` Start of line
- `(` Start of capturing group
- `.*` Anything zero or more times
- `[^\(]` Anything but an opening parentheses
- `\d{4}` Four digit date
- `[^\)]?` Anything but a closing parentheses (optionally)
- `)` End of capturing group
- `$` End of line

https://regex101.com/r/zr2pfv/1

Comment: Your linked version of `^(.*[^\(]\d+[^\)])$` captures the lines successfully, but the one in your text answer `^(.*[^\(]\d{4}[^\)]?)$` doesn't. Why does defining exactly 4 digits fail, but one or more with `+` works?

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe yes, sorry, I had initially used `\d+`, then noticed you wanted `\d{4}`. The problem with `d{4}` and my initial answer is that I was forcing to have something between the date and the end of the line. That's why I added the `?` to make that character optional.

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe this is even simpler: `^(.*[^\(]\d{4})$` https://regex101.com/r/sgaACW/1/

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe or this: `^(.* \d{4})$` https://regex101.com/r/SELsPU/1

Answer (score 2):

You could try matching on the next immediate character. For example:

```regex
\d{4}\s*$
```

This matches the lines containing exactly 4 digits as the last non-whitespace characters.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention anything about whitespace at the end of the string, so I'm not sure how this answer is relevant...

Comment: That's a fair point. I noticed that too, hence `*`. And since I've been in situations with trailing whitespaces messing up my regexes. That's why I included `\s`.

Answer (score 2):

Use more or less current centuries:

```js
\b(?:19|20)\d\d$
```

Or, any four digits as a whole word at the end of string:

```js
\b\d{4}$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/vlPZKq/1).

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    19                       '19'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    20                       '20'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                      word boundary
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4}                    four digits
```